# Why $n \log n$ is a polylogarithm?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I'm studying algorithms, and my lecture notes say that:

> Any polylogarithm grows slower than any polynomial: $(\log n)^a \prec n^b$ for $a, b>0$. Examples: $(\log n)^3 \prec \sqrt{n}$, $n\log n \prec n^2$.

I don't understand why $n \log n$ is a polylogarithm?

Polylogarithms seem to be of the form $(\log n)^a$, while this one is of the form $\log (n^a)$.

Comment: Who says $n\log n$ is a polylogarithm?  The usual definition, in this context, is just "a polynomial in $\log n$."  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithmic_function) for instance.  There's something else called a [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) but I doubt that's what you had in mind.

Comment: Should note:  the fact that 'ploylogarithm' includes the letters in the word 'algorithm' does not mean that 'algorithms' is an appropriate tag here.

Comment: Note that $n^2= n \cdot n$ so $\log n$ is the polylogorithm, not $n \log n$ in this statement.

Comment: @lulu I say it, because it's provided as an example of the statement "Any polylogarithm grows slower than any polynomial", and it is reasonable that if you make an example of this statement, the example contains a polylogarithm

Comment: @CyclotomicField I didn't get that. We divide both terms by $n$ and obtain $\log n \prec n$? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: I don't understand.  Nothing in the excerpt you quoted refers to $n\log n$.  We have a reference to $(\log n)^a$ which is obviously a polynomial in $\log n$ (trusting that $a$ is a natural number).

Comment: @lulu The left hand side of the second example is $n \log n$

Comment: Ah, fair point. That's not a polylogarithm.  The inequality is true, of course.  And it follows the fact that $\log n < n$.  But, as stated, it is not itself an example of a polylogarithm.

Comment: @robertspierre yeah that's what I'm suggesting. It's the only way I can interpret it without it being wrong.